# Matching Hrefs in plain text using regEx fails as soon as one link is touched

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays

I am currently writing a code-snippet that automatically links certain keywords and saves the links it linked into an array called `linked`. I do this last step to prevent a certain word to be linked twice.

Now the user is writing into a textbox, writes a keyword it gets linked. That works fine. My problem now is I am trying to handle the situation when he deletes text from the textbox. This means I have to match all links in the text against the linked array and then remove those from the linked array, that aren't in the text anymore. So far the theory. Unfortunately I am stuck with the following error.

Assume we have a text like this:

```
Test <a href='link1'>Link1</a> <a href='link2'>Link2</a>
```

I use this regEx (/href='([^\'\"]+)'/g) to get all the hrefs in the text above like so:

```
var hrefs = $(textInput).val().match(/href='([^\'\"]+)'/g);
```

This gives me an array that contains the following:

> href='link1'
>
> href='link2'

If I start deleting text and end up with something like this:

```
Test <a href='link1'>Link1</a> <a href='link2
```

Notice the one ' that is gone, the whole regEx turns out undefined, even though there still is a link in the string. Since I am not an expert with regEx I can't see exactly why? Is there maybe a better regEx for this situation?

Comment: If you're using a capture group, why are you using the `.match()` method? It is only good for just that... matching. Look into `.exec()` instead for extracting just the links.

Comment: `"Test <a href='link1'>Link1</a> <a href='link2".match(/href='([^\'\"]+)'/g);` returns `["href='link1'"]` correctly by the way (in console).

Comment: @tenub I know it does, that was later handled by .replace, however by now I changed to it to ´.exec()´ Thanks for that hint, did not know about it.

Comment: You are doing this update on-the-fly?  As they are typing?

Comment: I agree with @tenub, works 'correctly by the way (in console).' It works!,.. although it has unnecessary escapes. It could be simply `/href='([^']+)'/g`. So what's the problem? I can't duplicate that when "one ' that is gone, the whole regEx turns out undefined".

Comment: The other answers below work, but so does the OP's regex in his question.. I'm not sure OP 'really' had a problem with the result of his regex to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex like this:

```
/href='[^']+'/g
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/tU2qL0

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `/href=('|")\w+('|")/g` like this;

var hrefs = $(textInput).val().match(/href=('|")\w+('|")/g);

This should give you the matches.

BTW, `match()` is correct. Don't do `exec()` as @tenub said

Mark it as answer if it helps :)